# The given key was missing from the dictionary of type string

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hello i have a dictionnary of type string string with index int :

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

I want to acces in my view to the information with key "Total" and this what i did in my code :

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> Mydictionnarycollection = Helper.Dictionary();

Mydictionnarycollection[0]["Total"]
```

Here i have an error in the second statement (Mydictionnarycollection[0]["Total"]) which is :

> The given key was missing from the dictionary.

Comment: I did it but i have an error (  Invalid expression term " [ "  )

Comment: the variable also seems to be datesMontants, not Mydictionarycollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is accessed by key not by index. so try:

```
Mydictionnarycollection[10]["Total"]
```